# Use default argument if argument is None on python method call

Tags: python

Kind of a strange question, but I stumbled upon this one while coding.

This is my code

**EDIT:** I added classes to make my structure clearer

```
class Hidden(object):
    def x(self, aa, bb="John Doe"):
        print aa, bb

class Open(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.h = Hidden()

    def y(self, a, b=None):
        # get rid of this if-else-foo
        if b is None:
            self.h.x(a)
        else:
            self.h.x(a, b)

o = Open()
o.y("Hello") # > Hello John Doe

o.y("Hello", "Mister X") # > Hello Mister X
```

If `b` is `None` (not set), I want method `x` to be called without the argument (using the default).

I wonder if there's a way to get rid of the if-else foo?

**SOLUTION**

As I can only accept one answer, I can say, that all listed solutions work.

Here's my summary for the given answers:

1. @Duncan : for me it is the nicest way to achieve what I want.
2. @falsetru : it is also a nice approach, although I think methods with `*args` are hard to read.
3. @peter-wood and @tgg : both version work and save 3 lines of code. But an `if` statement remains, which I wanted to avoid.

Comment: Why are you calling y when you can just call x in the same manner? What's the point of y?

Comment: I think perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question, because when I call `x("Hello")`, I get `> Hello John Doe`. I don't see why `y` is needed. Is this not what you want?

Comment: It is just a simple example :) I have bigger classes and want to "mask" the one including `x`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your updated question with the classes, the easy way is just to alias `self.h.x` as `y`:

```
class Open(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.h = Hidden()
        self.y = self.h.x
```

and now when you call `o.y(...)` you're actually just calling `Hidden.x`:

```
o = Open()
o.y("Hello") # > Hello John Doe

o.y("Hello", "Mister X") # > Hello Mister X
```

Comment: Thanks, this a really elegant way, didn't think of that!

Answer (score 8):

If you can modify `x`:

```
def x(a, b=None):
    b = "John Doe" if b is None else b 
    print a, b
```

Comment: Thanks, yet another `if` construct, but shorter than before!

Comment: b = b or "John Doe"

Comment: @ioganegambaputifonguser, that will replace a empty string (or any other falsy value) to `'John Doe'`.

Comment: @ioganegambaputifonguser That's not the same: `x('Hello', '')` would behave differently

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get rid of 'if' just do

```py
self.h.x(a, [b, 'Default Value'][b is None])
```

ps. this works in python3.5+ and i don't care about python2.7

Comment: Thanks for this! I was really coding 2.7 back then, so this wouldn't be an option :)

Answer (score 4):

How about using variable length parameter (`*args`):

```
def y(*args):
    x(*args)
```

Then, there's no meaning of defining `y`!

```
y = x
```

---

**UPDATE**

adjusted `y` method according to question update. But the point is still valid; use `*args` for arbitrary length parameter:

```
class Open(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.h = Hidden()

    def y(self, *args):
        self.h.x(*args)

    # Alternative: explicitly pass `a` for readability
    #
    # def y(self, a, *args):
    #     self.h.x(a, *args)
```

Comment: See my edit, x is inside a "hidden" class and shouldn't be called directly.

Comment: Thanks, nice one, works as expected. Although I am not a big fan of using `*args`, as it reduces readability.

Comment: @ppasler, How about this (added to answer code for completeness)? `def y(self, a, *rest): self.h.x(a, *args)`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your function x works exactly as intended.

```
def x(a, b="John Doe"):
   print a, b
```

Then:

```
>>> x('Hello')
Hello John Doe
>>> x('Hello','Mister X')
Hello Mister X
```

But if you really want to, you can do:

```
def x(a, b="John Doe"):
   if b == None: b = "John Doe"
   print a, b
```

Comment: You are right, I also thought of that, but it also has a `if`. I thought of something built-in I missed.

Comment: You should compare with `None` using `is`, not `==`.